# Subtract more than one array using DeleteCases

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to create an array subtracting two arrays from another array. I know how to subtract one:

```
am = DeleteCases[amp, Alternatives @@ af]
```

I can subtract an array each time but there must be a way to subtract more than one array at once. So I want to subtract `af` and `ai` from `amp`. How can I do that at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select` as well :

```
ar = Range[10];
ar1 = Range[1, 10, 2];
ar2 = Range[1, 10, 3];

Select[ar, Not[MemberQ[Union[ar1, ar2], #]] &]
(* {2, 6, 8} *)

DeleteCases[ar, _?(MemberQ[Union[ar1, ar2], #] &)]
(* {2, 6, 8} *)
```

Comment: Or, `DeleteCases[ar, Alternatives @@ Union[ar1, ar2]]`.

Comment: `Not@MemberQ` is equivalent to `FreeQ`.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in function [Complement](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Complement.html)
does exactly what you need:

[image]

With

```
ar = Range[10];
ar1 = Range[1, 10, 2];
ar2 = Range[1, 10, 3];
```

elements in the first list that are not in any of the subsequent lists are:

```
Complement[ar, ar1,ar2]
(* {2, 6, 8 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {9, 4, 7, 1, 5, 3, 8, 5, 7, 3, 1, 0};
b = {7, 5};
c = {8, 3};
```

`DeleteElements` (new in 13.1) keeps duplicates and is equal with the
accepted answer

```
DeleteElements[a, Join[b, c]]
```

{9, 4, 1, 1, 0}

`UniqueElements` (also new in 13.1) deletes duplicates

```
Join @@ UniqueElements[{a, b, c}]
```

{9, 4, 1, 0}

Compare to other answers:

kglr's solution sorts the elements and deletes duplicates

```
Complement[a, b, c]
```

{0, 1, 4, 9}

The accepted answer doesn't sort and keeps duplicates

```
Select[a, Not[MemberQ[Union[b, c], #]] &]
```

{9, 4, 1, 1, 0}

Answer (score 1):

Using eldo's data:

```
a = {9, 4, 7, 1, 5, 3, 8, 5, 7, 3, 1, 0};
b = {7, 5};
c = {8, 3};
```

An alternative is to use `ReplaceAll`:

```
a /. Thread[Join[b, c] -> Nothing]

(*{9, 4, 1, 1, 0}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the data from @eldo we can use [**`UniqueElements`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UniqueElements.html) which was introduced in **v13.1**

```
a = {9, 4, 7, 1, 5, 3, 8, 5, 7, 3, 1, 0};
b = {7, 5};
c = {8, 3};
Flatten[UniqueElements[{a, b, c}]]
```

> `{9, 4, 1, 0}`